# ActiveRecord object serialization and deserialization to the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, serialization, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3

I would like to **deserialize** an serialized object.  So it's possible to process such as (with JSON):

```
>> l = Yea.create(:title => "foo bar")
=> #<Yea id: 3, title: "foo bar", created_at: "2010-07-05 21:44:54", updated_at: "2010-07-05 21:44:54">
>> j = l.to_json
=> "{\"yea\":{\"created_at\":\"2010-07-05T21:44:54Z\",\"title\":\"foo bar\",\"updated_at\":\"2010-07-05T21:44:54Z\",\"id\":3}}"
>> Yea.delete(3)
=> 1
>> a = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(j)
=> {"yea"=>{"created_at"=>"2010-07-05T21:44:54Z", "title"=>"foo bar", "updated_at"=>"2010-07-05T21:44:54Z", "id"=>3}}
>> Yea.create(a[:yea])
=> [#<Yea id: 4, title: "foo bar", created_at: "2010-07-05 21:44:54", updated_at: "2010-07-05 21:44:54">]
```

But I would like to write this a little bit more generic, using some thing like:

```
ActiveRecord.create(a)
```

rather than:

```
Yea.create(a[:yea])
```

Do you know how to do so?  Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be as straighforward as:

```
require 'yaml'
@article = YAML::load(@serialized_copy)
```

Comment: Thanks for answered.  But this isn't, 'cause I would like to load though ActiveRecord (or ActiveModel) to the DB.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just store the ID? This would allow you to stream the ID anywhere and not bother with the content.

Comment: No, I just would like to load a serialized object (in YAML or JSON) inside the DB. Is there a more generic way then: Article.create(ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(@article.to_json)[:article]), without specifying "article"?

Comment: Are you looking for the serialize class-method?  http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M001799